# Titanium studio - compatibility

Tags: titanium, compatibility, appcelerator

Pretty basic question ...

I can not find the compatibility table (was looking at it once) for services that Titanium studio can deal whit (light sensor, notification, mail, accelerometer, ...)...

If anyone has it ... please give me link!

Thanks a lot!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that hard to do a Google search? http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix

Comment: Found that ... but about half year ago there was a table comparing which sensors to can be used by Titanium ... now I can not see theme...